# Kivy: making in-memory PNG image from SVG string

Tags: svg, kivy, png

Below both blocks work:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
from svglib.svglib import SvgRenderer
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import ElementTree

svg="""<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>"""

parser =etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True,recover=True)

doc=etree.fromstring(svg,parser=parser)
et=ElementTree(doc)

sr=SvgRenderer("path")
drawing =sr.render(et.getroot())

pil=renderPM.drawToPMCanvas(drawing).toPIL()
window=tk.Tk()
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil)
lbl=tk.Label(window,image=img).pack()
```

and:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM
from svglib.svglib import SvgRenderer
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO                                        

svg="""<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>"""

parser =etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True,recover=True)

et=etree.parse(StringIO(svg),parser=parser)

sr=SvgRenderer("path")
drawing =sr.render(et.getroot())

pil=renderPM.drawToPMCanvas(drawing).toPIL()
window=tk.Tk()
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil)
lbl=tk.Label(window,image=img).pack()
```

I would like to be able to display images in Kivy: is it possible to build an in-memory PNG like above but using kivy.core[.image ?] libraries... ? (and get rid of tkinter, PIL etc.)

Thanks a lot.
Seb